# Redis get specific value based on zscore long in scala

Tags: scala, redis

I want to get values from Redis based on zscore. My zscore value is long value which is nothing but a timestamp in long. So, right now I'm fetching the data using :-

```
client.zrangeWithScore(key, 0, -1)
```

So, with this I'm able to fetch entire block but I want to fetch after specific zscore entry. My score is something like this type of values - 1523336885423.

Please suggest specific function along with its jar. Right now I'm using Scala-redis library of github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. We can use

```
client.zrangebyscoreWithScore(key, startidx, true, Double.PositiveInfinity, true, None)
```

1) startidx is starting index from where you want to start fetching the record.

2) Double.PositiveInfinity is end zscore , in my case it was till the end.

3) true defines whether to include starting or end zscore or not in the result set.

4) None - defines the sort order by default its ascending.

Thanks,